# Same result every time with random numbers (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, tkinter

```
def gDiceRoll():

    gDiceOptions.destroy()

    global gDiceRoll
    gDiceRoll = Tk()
    gDiceRoll.title("Green Dice Roll")
    gDiceRoll.config(background="#32cd32")

    lbloutcome = Label(gDiceRoll, text="?", width="12", height="8", bg="#32cd32")

    play()

    while True:

        outcomeG = random.randint(1, 100)
        lbloutcome = Label(gDiceRoll, text="?", width="12", height="8", bg="#32cd32")

        if outcomeG <= 25:

            lbloutcome.config(text="G1", font=(25))
            gDiceRoll.update()
            f = open("Logs.txt", "a")
            ts = time.time()
            sttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
            f.write(sttime + "G1 \n")
            f.close()
            photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Temp\Dice_Roll\pics\G1.gif")
            lblop = Label(gDiceRoll, image=photo)
            lblop.pack()
            lbloutcome.pack()
            gDiceRoll.mainloop()
            gDiceRoll.after(1)
            os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
            break

        elif outcomeG <= 22:

            lbloutcome.config(text="G2", font=(25))
            gDiceRoll.update()
            f = open("Logs.txt", "a")
            ts = time.time()
            sttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
            f.write(sttime + "G2 \n")
            f.close()
            photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Temp\Dice_Roll\pics\G2.gif")
            lblop = Label(gDiceRoll, image=photo)
            lblop.pack()
            lbloutcome.pack()
            gDiceRoll.mainloop()
            gDiceRoll.after(1)
            os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
            break        
        #etc
```

Every time I run the program ir **ALWAYS** comes out with G1. I have tried to fix it many ways but they just create other problems. The elif G1 <= 25 means it has a 25% chance of doing G1 but it always does G1.

**How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated**

Comment: of course `outcomeG <= 25` is stronger than `outcomeG <= 22`.

Comment: You also need to revise the priority of `if`/`elif` statements

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code. You only call `randint` once before calling `mainloop`, and you should never call `mainloop` in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How would I make it so the `if outcomeG <= 25` has a 25% chance of doing the code in that if statement?

Comment: 25% chance needs to be countermanded by 75% chance of something else. If you re-cast a random value if it's above 25% then there's 100% chance that you're entering in your code after (statistically) 4 tries. It's like playing heads & tails and stopping only if you get heads. you need a "G3" case when the value is > 25

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say `outcomeG <= 22`

then your code encounters `outcomeG <= 25` condition first, and enters first condition, *always*.

You have to swap your `if` and `elif` to test `<=22` first

Of course you have to *do* something if `outcomeG > 25` else you're looping for nothing.